# What does a dB represent in WebAudio's DynamicsCompressorNode

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, web-audio-api

The [`DynamicsCompressorNode`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-dynamicscompressornode-interface) in WebAudio API allows control over attack and release speed in units of seconds per 10dB.

Does this dB represent the ratio between two arbitrary units used in the system, or does it represent the power ratio between two waveforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Decibels (dB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) represent the ratio of two quantities on a logarithmic scale.

In the specific case of the attack and release speed units of the [`DynamicsCompressorNode`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-dynamicscompressornode-interface), it is used to represent the ratio of the `DynamicsCompressorNode`'s gain at two moments.

For example the default value of the `release` parameter is set to 0.25 seconds per 10dB. If we convert this 10dB into linear scale, we get `10^(10/20)` or approximately 3.16. This then means that if the `DynamicsCompressorNode`'s gain is initially set to 1, then 0.25 seconds later the gain could have increased to 3.16 (in response to a input signal with reduced power). Another 0.25 seconds later the gain could have changed to 3.16*3.16 = 10.

Similarly, the default value of the `attack` parameter is set to 0.003 seconds per 10dB. This then means that if the `DynamicsCompressorNode`'s gain is initially set to 1, then 0.003 seconds later the gain could have decreased to 1/3.16 (in response to a input signal with increased power). Another 0.003 seconds later the gain could have changed to (1/3.16)*(1/3.16) = 1/10 = 0.1.

Comment: I see. What about threshold? Does the range 0dB to -100dB for the threshold parameter correspond to the gain values of 1 and 0.00001 respectively? How does the compressor know at which gain level should the compressor start taking effect?

Comment: You got the values right for the threshold parameters, but it then refers to the input amplitude. The compressor keeps track of an input amplitude estimate. When that input amplitude exceeds the threshold, the compression starts taking effect.